# Proper way to navigate between Login & Dashboard screens?

Tags: flutter, authentication

I am pretty new to Flutter,  and I want to check if the user is logged in when it starts the app. If he does, he goes automatically to his Dashboard screen, if not then he goes to Login screen.

My problem is that I don't have a navigation animation between the moment he connects/disconnects.

So I'm wondering if there is another way to do that, **especially when the Login screen does not have a bottom navigation bar**.

BTW I'm using `Provider` package as state management, and `PersistentBottomNavBar` for the navigation.

Here is my code:

main.dart:

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        title: 'My App',
        home: context.watch<AuthProvider>().isLoggued ? MainMenu() : LoginPage(),
    );
  }
}
```

main_menu.dart

```
class MainMenu extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MainMenuState createState() => _MainMenuState();
}

class _MainMenuState extends State<MainMenu> {
  PersistentTabController _controller = PersistentTabController(initialIndex: 0);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: PersistentTabView(
        context,
        controller: _controller,
        screens: _buildScreens(),
        items: _navBarsItems(),
        ...
      ),
    );
  }

  List<Widget> _buildScreens() {
    return [
      DashboardPage(),
      MessagesPage(),
      ProfilePage(),
    ];
  }

  List<PersistentBottomNavBarItem> _navBarsItems() {
    return [
      PersistentBottomNavBarItem(
        icon: Icon(CupertinoIcons.home),
        activeColorPrimary: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
        inactiveColorPrimary: CustomColors.backgroundPrimaryGray,
        routeAndNavigatorSettings: RouteAndNavigatorSettings(
          initialRoute: DashboardPage.routeName,
          routes: {
            LoginPage.routeName: (ctx) => LoginPage(),
            DashboardPage.routeName: (ctx) => DashboardPage(),
          },
        ),
      ),
      PersistentBottomNavBarItem(
        icon: Icon(CupertinoIcons.bubble_left),
        activeColorPrimary: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
        inactiveColorPrimary: CustomColors.backgroundPrimaryGray,
      ),
      PersistentBottomNavBarItem(
        icon: Icon(CupertinoIcons.person),
        activeColorPrimary: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
        inactiveColorPrimary: CustomColors.backgroundPrimaryGray,
      ),
    ];
  }
}
```

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

If you want an animation when switching between the loginpage and the homepage, consider using as AnimatedSwitcher as the child of you MaterialApp, which would animate if your provider changes the isLoggedIn value: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/AnimatedSwitcher-class.html

This does not work if both child widgets have the same key, so make sure to specify different ones by giving both widgets a key argument of different values (i.e. ValueKey(1) for the one and ValueKey(2) for the other)

Comment: Well, your idea seems working, but I have the issue where `context.watch` works only in one way (when I logout). If I log in, my screen is not refreshed, but it does when I log out. If you have an idea why...

This is what I do for now:

`child: context.watch<AuthProvider>().isLoggued ? MainMenu(key: ValueKey(1)) : SelectLoginTypePage(key: ValueKey(2))`

Comment: Are you calling notifylisteners() when you log in?

Comment: Yes. I finally replaced `context.watch` by `context.read` and call `Navigator.pushAndRemoveUntil` manually. Not the best solution to me, but it does the job.